# DraftJS - contentState.getBlockMap is not a function

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I'm trying to save `editorState` to DB and show back to editor. For this thing, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39558101)

Now, when I try to get current content and permanently save it using `convertToRaw`, It works fine. But when I try to use this data and transform raw to `contentState` using `convertFromRaw` I get following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: contentState.getBlockMap is not a function

Here is my code to convert `editorState` from saved state:

```
{
    const convertedState = convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(value))
    const editorValue = EditorState.createWithContent(convertedState);
}
```

This way, it shows data in editor but when I type something to rich editor. It prompts :

> Uncaught TypeError: contentState.getBlockMap is not a function

P.s. using `draft-js: '0.10.5'`

Comment: Show your full code.

Answer (score 6):

`EditorState` is an Immutable Record that represents the entire state of a Draft.js editor, which includes the `ContentState`, but they are different things.

An EditorState object maintains undo and redo stacks comprised of ContentState objects.

What you are probably looking for is :

```
const convertedState = convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(value))
const editorValue = EditorState.createWithContent(convertedState.getCurrentContent());
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this actually documented anywhere?