# React-draft-wysiwyg : state.get is not a function

Tags: reactjs, wysiwyg, draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

While trying to set initial value from react hook form it shows that state.get is not a function. I have looked at [this][1] initially but seems like its not working.

````
const { handleSubmit, formState, control, reset, register } = useForm<any>({
    defaultValues: {
      title: editData ? editData.title : "",
      description: editData ? EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(editData.description))) : null
    }
  });
<div className="wysiwyg-wrapper">
                  <Controller
                    control={control}
                    name={"description"}
                    render={({ field }) => {
                      return <Editor
                        editorState={field.value}
                        toolbarClassName="toolbarClassName"
                        wrapperClassName="wrapperClassName"
                        editorClassName="editorClassName"
                        onEditorStateChange={(editorState: any) => {
                          let check = convertToRaw(editorState?.getCurrentContent())
                          console.log(editorState)
                          setEditorDescription(JSON.stringify(check))
                          field.onChange(editorState);
                        }}
                      />
                    }}
                  />

                </div>```


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548380/react-draft-js-convertfromraw-not-working/39558101#39558101
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/346zL.png
````